# Safari iOS - change page title

Tags: html, ios, safari, title

I have a website on my PC and I want to access it from my iPhone.
In Safari, the title is the IP of my computer. Is there any way to change it to whatever I want?

Comment: Does the HTML you are accessing have the `<title>` tag set?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a title tag between the head tags in your HTML document.

Exemple :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>What Ever Title You Want For Your Page</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In Safari for iOS it's displaying the url instead of the title for some reason.

Comment: I've just found out that since iOS7, the title tag is ignored on Safari.   Source : http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review (in the part which is name "Title")

Comment: So it's not possible to change the title?

Comment: You can't change the title of the page on Safari for iOS7+. Only the URL will be displayed. I've found some people complaining about this on the apple discussion forum and it seems to be due to some design guidelines from Apple.

Comment: Maybe I can change the URL of the page from the IP of my computer to something else, but I don't know how to do this for free.